# ASP.NET MVC post not working on popup window

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, popup

I am using ASP.NET MVC, I have finished my project and I copied the .sln solution files to the server.

When I run it on the server, everything ok, but there is showing  exceptions for the Popup forms.

I have this controller

```
-- The Get method
public ActionResult Remove(int id)
{
    Person Person_to_remove = new Person() { Person_Id = id };

    return View(Person);
}

-- The Post method
[ActionName("Remove"), HttpPost]
public ActionResult Remove_post(int id)
{
    DB.Remove(id);

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And these views:
**Index View**

```
<table>
         <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Remove?</th>
         </tr>
    @foreach (var row in Model)
    {
         <tr>
            <td>@row.Name</td>
            <td>
              <a href= @Url.Action("Remove", new { id = row.Id }) target="popup" onclick="Open();">Remove</a>
              <script type="text/javascript">
                  function Open() {
                    window.open('@Url.Action("Remove", new { id = row.Id })', 'popup', 'width=450,height=250');
                    return false;
                  }
               </script>
            </td>
          </tr>
    }
   </table>
```

**Remove View** (As a popup window)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <main>
        <div>
            <h3>Confirm removing:</h3>
            <h1>@Model.Name</h1>
            <br />
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="updateParent();">Confirm</button> 
                    <a onclick="window.close()">Cancel</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </main>
}
```

The **Index** view use a default "Layout" layout and the **Remove** view use a "Popup" layout on the shared folder

This is the updateParent() script running on the "Popup" layout

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function updateParent() {
           window.opener.location.reload();
           window.close();
      }
</script>
```

On my computer the app works fine, but when running on the server the popup views won't post the form, they just close without updating the data.

But when using the same URL from the Popup window into a new tab, it works. but is not desired behaviour.

I don't know what is going on, i only changed the IP in the connection string.

Comment: when user clicks button submit why do you reload the document and close the window?

Comment: reloads the "parent" document the Index view.

Comment: You already have a redirect to action in your controller. All you need to submitting. But if the browser disrupts submission some unexpected beahaviour could happen.

Comment: yes, but the behavior is from index opens a new window it displays a message to request a confirm action from the user, once confirmed, updates the index view and close. Using only the redirectToAction will make the index view to be loaded in the new window.

Comment: how do you know you're not closing before submitting?

Comment: the method runs when the submit button is clicked. It works fine in my pc, but in the other (the server) it won't update.

Comment: Ok, i removed the "window.close()" method and it works. but now i need to close the window when submiting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the form was closing before submitting. Thanks to derloopkat for the tip.

To solve this I change Razor @Html.BeginForm() to name the form "PopUp".

```
Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { name = "PopUp", id = "PopUp" })
```

then modify the updateParent method, to submit the form.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateParent() {
        document.forms["PopUp"].submit(); <-- Added
        window.opener.location.reload();
        window.close();
    }
</script>
```

Don't know if it's the best way, but it works.